# Routing from controller to Custome route

Tags: zend-framework, routes

I want to route from controller to custom route

I make a custom route

```
  $reportRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('blogs/blog_id/:blog_id', array('module' => 'blogs', 'controller' => 'blog', 'action' => 'index','blog_id' =>NULL));

    $routesArray = array('blogs' => $reportRoute);

    $router->addRoutes($routesArray);
```

and I want to make rediorection from controller to index page 
I make like this, but it doesn't work

```
$this->_helper->redirector->gotoRoute(array('module' => 'blogs', 'controller' => 'blog', 'action' => 'index', 'blog_id' => $this->blog_id));
```

Comment: Try this: $this->_helper->redirector->gotoRoute(array('blog_id' => $this->blog_id), 'blogs');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are not passing the name of route as the second argument for gotoRoute method to build url.

So code should be like

```
$this->_helper->redirector->gotoRoute(array('module' => 'blogs', 'controller' => 'blog', 'action' => 'index', 'blog_id' => $this->blog_id),'blogs')
```